# Java TCP File Transfer Only Complete On First Attempt

Tags: java, file, sockets, tcp, transfer

Despite hours of researching this problem, I have made very little progress. According to my professor, the code should be working as written...

I have a server that stays open, and a client that requests a file. Once the client receives the file, the client closes.

When I open the server, I am able to transfer a complete .jpg image file. The client then closes while the server remains open. I start up another client and try to transfer the same image, and only a portion of the bytes are transferred/written to the disk. The file transfer is only completely successful for the first file transferred by the server!

Additionally strange, a simple .txt text file *never* successfully transfers. I believe the cause is on the server side because it remains open as opposed to the client, which starts over each time.

Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class ft_server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        /*
         * Asks user for port number and listens on that port
         */
        BufferedReader portFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the port you'd like to use: ");
        int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(portFromUser.readLine());

        if (portNumber < 1 || portNumber > 65535) {
            System.out.println("Please choose a port number between 1 and 65535.");
            return;
        }
        portFromUser.close();


        ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        /*
         * Finished with user input
         */

        /*
         * Continuously listens for clients:
         */
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String clientIP = clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
            System.out.println("The client " + clientIP + " connected!");

            String clientMessage = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("The client requested file: " + clientMessage);

            // Get file. If doesn't exist, let's client know.
            // Otherwise informs client of file size.
            File myFile = new File(clientMessage);

            if (!myFile.exists()) {
                outToClient.writeBytes("File does not exist!\n");
                return;
            } else {
                outToClient.writeBytes(String.valueOf((int)myFile.length()) + "\n");
            }

            // Create array for storage of file bytes:
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));

            // Read file into array:
            bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            // Send the file:
            outToClient.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            outToClient.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ft_client {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        int byteSize = 2022386;
        int bytesRead;

        /*
         * Asks user for IP and port:
         */
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter an IP address: ");
        String ipAddress = inFromUser.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a port: ");
        String port = inFromUser.readLine();

        Socket clientSocket;

        try {
            // Makes socket, port, and calls connect. Assumes it's TCP:
            clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, Integer.valueOf(port));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        // Creates InputStream from server to get file size and other messages:
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        // Anything written to this will be sent to the server:
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        // Asks for a file name to download from the server:
        System.out.println("What file do you want?: ");
        String message = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(message + "\n");
        inFromUser.close();

        // Listens for confirmation from server.
        // If the file exists, the file size is delivered here:
        String response = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("File size: " + response);
        if (response.equals("File does not exist!")) {
            return;
        }

        // Receives file from server:
        byteSize = (int) Integer.valueOf(response);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteSize];
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream(); // calling clientSocket.getInputStream() twice???
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(message);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);       

        // Continuously writes the file to the disk until complete:
        int total = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
            bos.write(byteArray, 0, bytesRead);
            total += bytesRead;
        }

        bos.close();
        System.out.println("File downloaded (" + total + " bytes read)");

        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Are buffered readers interfering with output streams? Is there a better way to transfer files?

Comment: Don't mix buffered and unbuffered streams and readers on the same socket. Find another way to send the filename, e.g. with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`, and read it with `DataInputStream.readUTF()`.

Comment: I will give it a try. But, is there something inherently wrong with mixing them?

Comment: The buffered reader, err, buffers. It reads some image data if it was already there when you read the filename.

Comment: Mixing the stream types is a bit bad, yes. The client sends the filename with `DataOutput.writeBytes(s)` which sends the bottom byte of each char; then the server is reading it with a `BufferedReader.readLine()` through a byte->char converter (`InputStreamReader`) using your system's default character encoding. You might be fine as long as you stick to plain ASCII, but if you have UTF-8 as your default encoding and a file with a non-ASCII char in its name, it'll all get horribly muddled.

Comment: @EJP Oh dear I can't see the Buffer problem you're talking about! Must be getting late. Aren't all the BufferedReaders being recreated each time round the server loop? And the client is restarted each time....?

Comment: @SusanW The client sends the filename and then the file. The buffered reader at the server will read up to 4096 chars or whatever its buffer size is from the input, including part of the image if it had already arrived, but only deliver the filename part, the bit that constitutes the first line. So when he goes to read the image with the input stream he's already lost part of it in the buffered reader. Surprising it worked at all.

Comment: @EJP Are you dead certain the client sends the file, not the server?  It might be that glass of red wine that's messing me up here, but I'm seeing the client send the filename (received by `inFromClient` on the server), and then the server replies with the file length then the content, both written to the (unbuffered) `outToClient`...

Comment: @SusanW Whatever. Whoever is reading the filename or file size or whatever the line is, and then the file, is losing part of the file in the buffered reader.

Comment: @EJP ok. I can't see any other read on the server socket than the filename, before the end of the loop, and then the BufferedReader is dropped. I can't make your explanation make sense.

Comment: @SusanW The buffered reader reads into its internal buffer, therefore it reads whatever data has arrived, which may include part of the image. It doesn't just stop at a newline when reading. That's why it's called a buffered reader.

Comment: To clarify, the client says to the server "I want this filename". The server then looks for the file, and sends it to the client.

Comment: @EJP I changed everything to DataInputStream/DataOutputStream, and I am now able to transfer image and text files on the first attempt. I have now put the Client in a loop in order to ask for more files. However, unless I call `outToClient.close()` on the output stream (server) the client never recognizes EOF/the end of the stream, and the program just pauses. If I _do_ call `.close()` I cannot request any more files, because the socket gets closed.

Comment: @EJP Ok - I get how they work. .... I just couldn't see how _that applied to this specific question_. Anyway - yes, ok, so you _are_ right. Yes. Problem on the client (I was focusing on the server), two accesses to the socket's input. Fine... and thanks!

Comment: @NickH If you want to send multiple files, you could just open a new connection, if the requests were likely to be rare and spread out, say over minutes. If you want to use the same connection - which you should if the requests are more dense - then the client needs to read _exactly_ the right number of bytes, as per the length you send, and _not_ read until EOF (-1). The server then won't close its return connection until it receives an EOF on the command stream from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth checking, in your server code, what value comes back from the  file `read()` call, so:

```
int bytesRead = bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
System.out.println("File bytes read: " + bytesRead + " from file size: " + myFile.length());
```

The `read()` method is under no obligation to fill the byteArray - only to return *something* and to tell you how many bytes it read. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)), it:

> Reads up to len bytes of data from this input stream into an array of
>   bytes. If len is not zero, the method blocks until some input is
>   available; otherwise, no bytes are read and 0 is returned.

You need to keep reading in a loop. I'd do this (actually, same as your client!):

```
int n;
while ((n = bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length)) != -1) {
    // Send the chunk of n bytes
    outToClient.write(byteArray, 0, n);
}
bis.close();
outToClient.close();
```

or something similar. I've closed the file too: it'd close on GC/finalize, but that could be a while, and meanwhile you're holding the file open.

**EDIT**

The specific problem with your image-read in this case is in your client code. You read the file size near the top of the code:

```
    // Creates InputStream from server to get file size and other messages:
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

and then you access the client again:

```
    InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream(); // calling clientSocket.getInputStream() twice???
```

and as your comment suggests, this is bad! Thank you to @EJP for highlighting this!

This causes a problem of buffer over-ingestion: the BufferedReader consumes more bytes into its belly than you extract from it, so when you visit the clientSocket inputstream the second time, the read-pointer has moved on. You never look again at what the BufferedReader consumed.

As a general rule, once you plug buffering code onto something, you must be careful to read *only* from that buffer. In this case, it's difficult, because you can't read image (raw binary) data from a Reader, because it will busily interpret the binary values as characters and read them as UTF-8 or something.

Even without buffers, it's a minor sin to mix Readers (text oriented) and binary data (DataStreams) on the same stream. HTTP and email does this, so you are in good company, but they get away with it by being very tightly specified. Problem is, you can easily get snarled with questions of local/default character encoding at each end, whether you're reading Unix "LF" vs Windows "CR/LF" line endings etc.

In this case, try not using BufferedReaders at all, and try using DataInput/Output streams all the way. Try `writeUTF(s)` and `readUTF()` for transferring the String data. Ideally, create them like this:

```
    DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

so you still get the benefits of buffering.

**EDIT 2**

So seeing the new client code:

```
        byteSize = (int) Integer.valueOf(response);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteSize];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(message);

        int readBytes = inFromServer.read(byteArray);

        // Continuously writes the file to the disk until complete:
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++) {
            fos.write(byteArray[i]);
            total++;
        }

        fos.close();
```

Here, we're assuming that because the `byteArray` array is set to the right size, that the `inFromServer.read(byteArray)` will populate it - it won't. It's good to assume that any and all read operations will return you just as much data as the system has to hand: in this case, it's probably going to return as soon as it gets the first packet or two, with an underfilled array. This is same as *C* and *Unix* read behaviour too.

Try this - I'm repeatedly reading and writing a 4K buffer, until the byte count is reached (as determined by summing the return values of the reads):

```
        byteSize = (int) Integer.valueOf(response);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[4096];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(message);
        int total = 0;
        // Continuously writes the file to the disk until complete:
        while (total < byteSize && (readBytes = inFromServer.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
            fos.write(byteArray, 0, readBytes);
            total += readBytes;
        }
        fos.close();
```

A variant is this - same thing, but byte at a time. Might be a bit clearer. It's going to be slow - all those reads and writes are hitting the OS, but if you put a BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream around the socket/file streams, it'll iron that out. I've added them:

```
    DataInputStream inFromServer = 
            new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ...         
        byteSize = (int) Integer.valueOf(response);

        OutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(message));
        int total = 0;
        int ch;
        // Continuously writes the file to the disk until complete:
        while (total < byteSize && (ch = inFromServer.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(ch);
            total ++;
        }
        fos.close();
```

And finally! the simplest answer is this. Your code, but changed to:

```
        int readBytes = inFromServer.readFully(byteArray);
```

Yes! Those nice people in 1990's Javasoft added a [DataInput.readFully](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully(byte[])) method, which does what you want! - basically wraps the code above. It's the simplest solution, and arguably most correct approach: "use existing libraries where possible". OTOH, it's the least *educational*, and the time you spend getting used to read/writes like this is *not deducted from your life-expectancy!*

And in fact, the `readFully` approach has severe limitations. Try pointing it at a 1GB file and see what happens (after you've fixed up the array size at the top): you'll a) run out memory, and b) wish that while you were ingesting a huge blob, you could at least be spooling it out to disk. If you try a 2.5G file, you'll notice that some of those ints should become longs to cope with numbers >= 2^31.

If it was me, I'd do the 4K buffer one. (BTW I'm writing this on a laptop with no Java compiler installed, so I haven't actually run the above! DO respond if there are any difficulties.)

Comment: For some reason `bis.read` was _never_ returning -1, so the program was just paused there. I just did away with the loop because it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @NickH added follow up about Buffers. The thing with not returning -1 .... that's weird! I mean, do be careful, I've lost count of how many times I've seen that assumption slip up, so at least check what it returns and alert if it's not what you expect.

Comment: I have changed all BufferedReaders to DataInput/OutputStreams. But now I have a different problem. I can `writeUTF` (from server, sending length of file as a String) and `readUTF` from client just fine on the _first_ attempt. When the loop starts it's second time through, `writeUTF` from the server works, but `readUTF` in the client throws: "java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 0". Something is happening with the stream. First time through it sends the String just fine, second time there is something else going on.

Comment: Additionally, I've changed `writeUTF` to `writeInt` and it sends the correct file size the first time. Second time through, when calling `readInt` from the client, instead of reading the correct size (which presumably was sent), it reads some very large _negative_ number. I have no idea where this comes from. Somewhere between `writeInt` and `readInt` the correct file size in is being changed to a large, negative int, and that's what the client is reading it as!

Comment: @NickH Hmm, hard to tell without seeing the code. Sounds like somewhere you're getting more or fewer bytes coming through - perhaps from the image content, and then the next size message becomes out of alignment. The big negative number is likely coming from the client trying to read the wrong bytes as the int. Do make sure that every single  `read` return value  is checked.

Comment: After calling readUTF (or readInt, etc), are the bytes that are read removed from the input stream? Cause it seems like bytes are staying in there, even after being read. Thus the next time through, readUTF is reading bytes for the new writeUTF and some left over from the previous.

Comment: @NickH Absolutely. It's a golden rule, what gets written must get read and removed. This IS odd. Can you post your code somewhere? Stick it in an Answer or something - I'll take a look. Two pairs of eyes...

Comment: Here are dropbox links to my client and server. Explanation of behavior is in the server file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn6r48wl7mjehkd/ft_server.java?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/530q95mubtg1ndc/ft_client.java?dl=0

Comment: @NickH ok, thanks. Yep - the reads are coming up short. Rule: assume that _any_ read will return a shortfall; when reading a file or a socket, the system may return you the first _something_, with more to come. I'll amend answer with suggestion.